# Valid actionSource name/targets for nested components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, composite-component

Given following implementation, what's the correct value to set in composite:actionSource@name or @targers so that my actionSource refers to a4j:commandButton@id="yes"

```
<composite:implementation>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Delete selected" execute="@this"
                       oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmDeletePopup')}.show()"/>
    <rich:popupPanel id="confirmDeletePopup">
        <h:form id="confirmForm">
            <a4j:outputPanel id="confirmDeletePanel" styleClass="popup">
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.deleteSelectedBean.selection}">
                    Are you sure?

                    <div class="popupButtons">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Yes" id="yes"
                                           execute="@this" 
                                           action="#{cc.attrs.deleteSelectedBean.deleteSelected()}"
                                           oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmDeletePopup')}.hide(); return false"/>
                        <h:commandButton styleClass="yesNo"
                                         value="No" immediate="true">
                            <rich:componentControl target="confirmDeletePopup" operation="hide" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty cc.attrs.deleteSelectedBean.selection}">
                    First choose what you want to delete!
                    <div class="popupButtons">
                        <h:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true">
                            <rich:componentControl target="confirmDeletePopup" operation="hide" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </rich:popupPanel>
</composite:implementation>
```

EDIT:
As of now, I tried name="yes":

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="deleteSelectedBean" type="pl.aw.presentation.common.DeleteSelectedEntitiesBean"/>
    <composite:attribute name="render" />
    <composite:actionSource name="yes"/>
</composite:interface>
```

Trying to refer to the actionSource as follows:

With the listener as follows:

```
public class OrganizationListBean {
    //...
    public ActionListener getDeleteListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
                System.out.println("listener run");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the code is not executed.

I have also tried adding (proposed by Intellij Idea autocomplete) `targets="confirmDeletePopup:confirmForm:confirmDeletePanel:yes"` but then I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: confirmDeletePopup
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:612) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.AttachedObjectTargetImpl.getTargets(AttachedObjectTargetImpl.java:96) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.jar:2.1.29-03]
```

I use JBoss EAP 6.1.Alpha with Mojarra upgraded to jsf-impl-2.1.29-03.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/composite/actionSource.html) seems pretty clear:

- `targets` - id(s) of the button(s)
- `name` - id of the button in case you don't set `targets`, otherwise it's just an identifier

So you set name="yes".

Comment: What doesn't work? I assume you have an actionListener somewhere, show the code.

Comment: the listener code is not executed, please see my edited post

Comment: I meant what does the code with `f:actionListener` look like, it may not be properly registered (and the processAction method should be public if that is the actual code).